# TableViewCell subclass not getting initialized

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to create a custom tableViewCell programmatically.
This is what I do:

1. Creating a tableViewCell subclass and importing it to the tableViewController
2. In the tableViewController m:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoreCell";

   CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   return cell;}
   ```
3. In the CustomCell m:

   ```
   -(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
   {

       self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
       if (self) {

       NSLog(@"Hello!");

       }
       return self;
   }
   ```

(Sorry for not getting the code highlighting thing to work)

My problem is that the CustomCell don't get initialized. The initWithStyle never gets triggered. I followed a couple of tutorials and they do the exact same thing, but successfully..

Comment: Did you set the tableview delegate ?

Comment: No I did not. I have now, and it works :)

Comment: In the app delegate I set the tableViewController as the window.rootViewController. Is that what you mean? And what if you want to use the custom table cells in multiple viewControllers?

Comment: No this is not what I mean. In your initialization just do : tableview.delegate = self; tableview.datasource = self;

Comment: I tried adding those lines to the initWithStyle method of the viewController, but it seems the method doesn't get called..

Comment: I have, but I really can't figure it out. Can you help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The cells didn't get initialized because I was using prototypes cells in the storyboard. I set the prototypes cells to 0 and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 6, dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: always returns a cell, so your if-case never gets called.
If a cell with that identifier is not available, it initializes it itself.
Try implementing initWithCoder: in the UITableViewCell subclass, that's what gets called in that case.

Comment: So i just replace initWithStyle with initWithDecoder? Should I call the method from the viewController? Also, what happens if you have older iOS than 6?

Comment: Basicly, yes. It will get called automatically from the UITableView-instance requesting a Cell. In Addition, if you're using pre-iOS6, calling dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: will crash the application. Go with the other answer in that case or determine the iOS version at runtime and decide then.

Answer (score 1):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath try this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoreCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why fall back on iOS5-Methods without the need to do so? He's obviously developing for iOS6, so why use the 'old' methods instead of making the 'new' method do what he wants? (implementing initWithCoder: on the TableViewCell-subclass)